# How to wrap elements when having their parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class='wrap1'>
 <div class='element1'></div>
 <div class='element2'></div>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to get:

```
<div class='wrap1'>
 <div class='anotherWrap'><!-- this is new-->
  <div class='element1'></div>
  <div class='element2'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

That is, I need to wrap `element1` and `element2` in `anotherWrap`.

I tried:

```
$('.wrap1').children().wrapAll("<div class='anotherWrap'></div>")
```

But, as I expected, this wrapped every sub div in my `wrap1` div separately.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: you need [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: FYI : `$('.wrap1').children().wrapAll("<div class='anotherWrap'></div>")` works  fine. see this http://jsfiddle.net/5twpkbfr/

Comment: Is just me or your example works fine?

Comment: Well, not really. Although chrome developer tools show that everything's fine it isn't.  When I do  var x=$('.wrap1').children().wrapAll("<div class='anotherWrap'></div>") and then x.css('border','1px solid red'); I can see two elements with red borders. Plus console.log(x) shows two elements as well instead of just one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.wrapInner()` over the parent element,

```
$('.wrap1').wrapInner("<div class='new' />");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jr48kqLL/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to do but didn't find any solution. I used the following work around. Hope this will work for you..

```
$('.wrap1').prepend("<div class='anotherWrap'>").append("</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$( ".element1,.element2" ).wrapAll( "<div class='anotherWrap'></div>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jr48kqLL/)**

Answer (score 1):

3rd use `.contents()`:

```
$('.wrap1').contents().wrapAll("<div class='anotherWrap'></div>");
```

#### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4tbtoga2/.